# Using shared preferences vs. bundle in Android

Tags: android

The app I'm making retrieves between 1 and 2 dozen records from a table in a DB so that certain pieces of data can be used during the app (the table has 6 fields). It won't need to be stored permanently on the device. Is shared preferences used for something like this or should I be utilizing a bundle?

Comment: can you explain more? as far as I understand you get data from DB on start of the app and you want to use this data in different activity in your app. Is it right?

Comment: Correct. I suspect I may be making my question a little vague though. This is an exercise I'm doing just for the sake of learning how to make Android apps. I've managed to connect to a remote DB on a server with my app. I've been trying to figure out if there's an efficient way of holding the data I retrieve and displaying at on the screen.

Comment: Please check my answer. You can just query the db.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just query the db and get the data you want and store it in a normal fashion in variables.

**SharedPreferences** is mainly used when you want to retain data between different **app executions**.

**Bundle** is used when you want to safely transfer data between activities or between an activity and a fragment.

So unless you have some such requirements, you can just store them in normal *variables*.

Comment: Thanks Gautham. With PHP I'd make six variables and then do a loop that queries the DB and prints the data to the screen using these variables. I was curious to find examples showing it's basically the same in Android. I'm assuming from your comment that it is?

Comment: I haven't worked on php.. but from your comment I gather it is just  essentially that. Though you would have to make sure you would store them in an *array* of variables instead of just variables , since, you are doing it in a loop.

Comment: Assuming you want to save the data of all the entries that you are querying, perhaps for some later use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access to same data from different activities and also if you are not going to store them permanently, you can use static variables in a class of your app. So;

```
// create static variable in a class

class SomeClassName {

    public static ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects;

}
```

init the list when you get it from DB

```
SomeClassName.myObjects = GET_ITEMS_AND_REFERENCE_THEM;
```

then use it in another class like this

```
MyObject myObject = SomeClassName.myObjects.get(0);
```